# Python | TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python

I am using the following code to extract some features from audio files, an write them in numpy array files:

```
def calc_ceps(file_list, index, label, method=None, n_mfcc=None, s_rate=None):    
    '''Calculates and saves ceps'''

    if method == None:
        method = 'librosa'
    if s_rate == None:
        s_rate = 22050
    if n_mfcc == None:
        n_mfcc = 20    

    print 'Wave to Ceps:'
    total = len(file_list)    

    for i, file in enumerate(file_list):         

        if method == 'librosa':
            ceps = np.array(librosa.feature.mfcc(*read_wave(file), n_mfcc=n_mfcc))
            ceps.shape = (len(ceps[0]), n_mfcc)

        elif method == 'talkbox':
            ceps = mfcc(read_wave(file)[0])[0]

        write_data('ceps', ceps, label[i], file)
        progress(i, total)  

    progress(199, 199)
```

the function *progress(current, total)* prints the progress, *file_popul()* provides the file list and *write_data()* writes the numpy array to file.

Calling:

```
>>>get_ceps(*file_popul())()
```

Whilst the *calc_ceps()* functions works 100% as intended (i.e. saves numpy arrays for ALL the files it gets), when it is over (i.e. written all the files) I get the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

pdb output with steps:

```
>>> calc_ceps(*file_popul())()    
Wave to Ceps:
99%> ~/final_project/code/utilities.py(122)calc_ceps()
-> progress(199, 199)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(16)progress()
-> def progress(current, maximum):
(Pdb) s
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(18)progress()
-> ratio = round((float(current) / float(maximum)), 2) * 100
(Pdb) s
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(19)progress()
-> if ratio < 100:
(Pdb) s
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(22)progress()
-> elif ratio == 100:
(Pdb) s
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(23)progress()
-> sys.stdout.write("\r100%  done! \n")
(Pdb) s
100%  done! 
--Return--
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(23)progress()->None
->sys.stdout.write("\r100%  done! \n")
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> ~/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(122)calc_ceps()->None
-> progress(199, 199)
(Pdb) s
TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable"
> <stdin>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>>>
```

using python 2.7

Thanks in Advance.

EDIT: Commented out `progress()` usage, this is what I get in pdb:

```
>>> calc_ceps(*file_enum())()
Wave to Ceps:
--Return--
> /home/mpir/python/final_project/code/utilities.py(121)calc_ceps()->None
-> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) s
TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable"
> <stdin>(1)<module>()
(Pdb) s
--Return--
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>>>
```

Ain't it strange?

Comment: Are you using `progress` both as a function name and as a variable?

Comment: Nope :/ . Commented out `progress` parts, still having the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calc_ceps function has no return statement, so `calc_ceps(*file_popul())` returns `None`, and you try to call it once again with one more pair of braces: `calc_ceps(*file_popul())()`